# program for comparisons in python

Tags: python, compare, new-operator

I'm really new to programming (really, really new) and need help with the basics. I'm trying to write a program with python that will compare the contents of two .txt files, one a reference and the other the source. The contents are a simple random listing of names, and I want it to print out if there are any names in the source that are not in the reference.

I've looked at other stuff on this site but every time I tried it, the terminal would never actually give a result, even if there was a print command in the program.

I also have a hard time reading the language of a program and ascertaining it's exact function, so something with clear directions would be really appreciated.

As far as I have is:

```
ref = open("reference.txt")
sor = open("source.txt")

list1 = ref.read()
list2 = sor.read()

for i in list2:
    if i != list:
    print i

ref.close()
sor.close()
```

And when I try and run this, it says "expected an indented block"? at the 'print i' line. Why?

Please help me out, as I have to teach myself this stuff and am not doing too well.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `try..finally` or the `with`-Statement to safely open and close files.

Answer (score 3):

If you are totally, completely new to programming then it will take you some time to be able to implement what you describe.  Take a step back, pour yourself a beverage, and start here.  Start at the beginning, and repeat each illustration until you understand.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, your inner if statement needs to be indented, as

```
for i in list2:
    if i != list:
        print i
```

This requires two indents because it is two nested blocks. As a basic rule of thumb, anywhere you're ending a line with a colon (`:`), you're starting a new code block, and should be indenting another level. This is so you can un-indent once to end the `if` block without ending the `for` block.

However, I doubt this will do what you want based on your description. It's likely you wanted something more like

```
sourceLines = set(sor.readLines())
for line in ref.readlines():
    if line not in sourcelines:
        print line
```

Comment: Isn't it `readlines()`, without capital `l`? Also as `readlines()` returns a list why `line for line in`?

Comment: This seemed liked it worked, but then it printed out lines that were present in each file, just in different places. Is there a way to compare every line with every other line in the file?

Comment: tomasz: You're right, thanks, edited to reflect.
computernewbie: Yes, but depending on what you want to do the algorithm is much more complicated. If you just want to do a line-by-line comparison, you can do `for (l1, l2) in zip(sor.readlines(), res.readlines()): if l1 != l2: print l1, '||', l2`, and get a very naive file diff program. Google around for 'diff program' if you want to see some more professional solutions. Many of them are based on algorithms like [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 0):

`if` blocks in python have to be indented, add another level of indent for your `print i` statement

```
for i in list2:
    if i != list:
        print i
```

Comment: Thanks, I did and it didn't work, so I added another and it started working but I'm not sure if my code does what I want it to. Why did it require 2 indents?

Comment: Each block in Python requires the contents of that block to be indented.  In this case you have a `for` block whose contents need to be indented and then inside that `for` block you have a nested `if` block that also needs to be indented further.

Comment: Because each control structure needs its own indentation block. In C++ you would have two blocks, too:

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your indentation error first: you need another 4 spaces before the print statement. In Python indentation is important and you need to indent any block and dedent to end that block.

For your problem I am going to not give you written out code in advance but more of a flow on how to do it:

1. Create 2 sets (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
2. Read both files into a seperate set (you can do this while iterating over a file and appending to your set).
3. Compare your two sets using the set1 - set2 syntax (see the link above) to show all items not common to both sets.

Hope you can make it work from this.

Now for the code:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    set1 = set(line for line in file1)

with open('file2.txt') as file2:
    set2 = set(line for line in file2)

print set1 - set2
```

This uses some principles you are probably not familiar with (look up: list comprehensions, generator comprehensions and the previously noted link about sets which are unique collections).

Comment: You should use `try..finally` or the `with`-statement to safely open and close files!

Comment: Quite correct, yes. Both could be wrapped in a with statement but for brevity and to avoid overcomplication I've left them out :-)

Comment: I need some time to actually edit the question as well but consider it done now ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried it though, and it says there it uses invalid syntax after the 'open' statement in 'open('file1.txt'). Why is that?

Comment: If you are using python 2.5 you need to add the following line to the top: 'from \_\_future\_\_ import with_statement'. If you are using an older version the with statement is not yet in Python so you could take it away and dedent the blocks. If you are using a newer version, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

These lines read the files as strings:

```
list1 = ref.read()
list2 = sor.read()
```

This loop iterates through the string one *character* at a time:

```
for i in list2:
```

This line compares the character to the `list` class:

```
    if i != list:
```